# Run line or command in R on a Mac

Tags: r

I am running R 3.0.0 on OSX Snow Leopard. 
I would like to run each line from the editor separately without having to copy and paste the commans. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Highlight the line, then `command-enter`.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, if you want to run all the stuff in a `.R` file you can use the `source` function.